# Verify specific input value

Tags: javascript, validation, webforms, conditional-statements

First off, thanks for anyone's help on this.  I have an input id #Mailer_Code.  I want to submit a specific value based on whether this mailer code value matches the user's value or not, and create 2 different IDs based on whether this value is valid or not.

In general terms:

ID is 1234;
if Mailer_Code is yourock, then ContactID is DWID
if Mailer_Code is not yourock, then ContactID is WWID

I would really appreciate if "yourock" was some sort of comma separated list so the Mailer_Code could be any of the specified values.  ie. #Mailer_Code  = "yourock, or yourawesome, or supercool, etc." (not case sensitive)

Also, if the #Mailer_Code is anything other than the list of allowed values, it simply returns a #Mailer_Code of "none" and WW1234.

So far I'm here:

```
if ( $('#Mailer_Code').val = "yourock" ) { 
contactSource = "DW";
mailer_true_false = "true";
}
else { 
contactSource = "WW";
mailer_true_false = "false"; 
$("#Mailer_Code").val('0');
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why are you using strings as booleans? is `true` and `false` actual strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you started.

Note that instead of a comma separated list of valid values I added them to an array.  jQuery has a very useful array function `inArray` that makes checking the values a simple matter.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="Mailer_Code">yourock</span>
        <span id="Id">1234</span>
    </div>
    <span id="ContactId"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = [ "yourock", "youareawesome", "youarethebest" ];
        var inListPrefix = "DW";
        var outListPrefix = "WW";
        var mailerCode = $("#Mailer_Code").text();
        var pre = "";

        if (jQuery.inArray(mailerCode, arr) >= 0)
        {
            pre = inListPrefix;
        }
        else
        {
            pre = outListPrefix;
            $("#Mailer_Code").text("none");
        }

        $("#ContactId").text(pre + $("#Id").text());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```